# How to Create a table in SQL Server to set Email Address to Active / Inactive

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql

Here is a summary of what I am trying to do.

1. User enters email address at initial user setup
2. That address is set to inactive and no insight reports are sent to it, either individually or as part of a subscriber group
3. A confirmation email is sent to that address with an activation link
4. When the link is clicked, the email address is set to active and Insight reports can be sent
5. If a user modifies an existing email address, the new address is set to inactive (go back to step 2)

My main struggle here is figuring out how to create a table that will be able to record initial emails as null / inactive.

I also figure that I could use a trigger to submit an email to the user.

Comment: "I also figure that I could use a trigger to submit an email to the user."

Maybe you can clarify your exact need regarding this

Comment: @codein Sorry for being vague, bit new here. My thought was to implement a trigger that would fire an email validation link when the user entered in their email. Ultimately, after creating the table, my next item would be to figure out a way to send an email to the user to validate them.

Comment: Aside: Rather than using a `bit` to record the activation of an email address you might want to use a nullable `datetime`, e.g. `ActivationConfirmedOn`. It gives you a little more information, e.g. if you want to check the activation vs. updated Terms & Conditions to determine whether to go through another activation cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a table having a flag for activity/inactivity which is NULL by default as below:

```
CREATE TABLE Subscription (
    id      INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    name    varchar(100),
    email   nvarchar(100),
    isActive bit DEFAULT NULL  --0 inactive, 1 active, for example
)
```

If you want the value: "inactive" as default, try `isActive varchar(10) DEFAULT 'inactive'` while creating the table.